AutoScroll Issue in React Native FlatList with Horizontal ScrollView
I'm working on a React Native application where I have two horizontally scrolling FlatList components wrapped inside a ScrollView. I'm trying to implement autoscrolling, but I'm encountering a problem with the initial scroll behavior.
When the user try scrolling to the left for the first time, the scroll doesn't work unless the user scroll to the right. Once I scroll to the right and then try scrolling left, it works as expected. However, this issue persists for the very first left scroll attempt.
Here’s a brief overview of my implementation:
1. I have two FlatList components displaying data horizontally.
2. The scrolling of the FlatList is animated, and I suspect it may interfere with the manual scroll behavior.
I suspect it has something to do with how the animation and the scroll events are being handled, but I can't pinpoint the issue. Has anyone experienced something similar or have any suggestions on how to fix this?
const handleScrollBegin = () => {
    if (timeoutRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
    isScrolling.current = true;
    scrollX.stopAnimation();
};

const handleScrollEnd = () => {
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        isScrolling.current = false;
        animateItems(currentScrollPosition.current).start();
    }, 2000);
};

// ScrollView with Animated.FlatLists
<ScrollView
    horizontal
    onScrollBeginDrag={handleScrollBegin}
    onScrollEndDrag={handleScrollEnd}
    onScroll={handleScroll}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
>

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Animated.FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderRow}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.row}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            style={{
              transform: [
                {
                  translateX: scrollX.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, width],
                    outputRange: [0, -width],
                  }),
                },
              ],
            }}
          />
         [A second Animated.Flatlist]

        </View>
</ScrollView>


try react-native-reanimated-carousel instead
ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated-carousel
